# style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay not found in new Google Place picker

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete, google-place-picker

> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
}
```

> Feature module Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.demo.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:onDemand="false"
    dist:title="@string/title_feature_module">
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>
<application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="12451000"
        tools:replace="android:value" />

    <activity android:name=".presenter.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="action.demo.open" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".presenter.map.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

    <service
        android:name=".service.FetchAddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

> Implementation

```
private fun startAutocompleteActivity() {
        val fields = listOf(
                Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS,
                Place.Field.ID,
                Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
                Place.Field.NAME
        )
        if (!Places.isInitialized())
            Places.initialize(applicationContext, getString(R.string.google_maps_key))

        val intentPlacePicker = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                .build(this)
        startActivityForResult(intentPlacePicker, KeyUtils.REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER)
    }
```

> I'm getting below issue

```
Android resource linking failed
/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/mockDebug/AndroidManifest.xml:98: error: resource string/places_autocomplete_label (aka com.demo.app.mock:string/places_autocomplete_label) not found.
/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/mockDebug/AndroidManifest.xml:98: error: resource style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay (aka com.demo.app.mock:style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your manifest?

Comment: @XaviJimenez I just added manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
 Add this to your app module gradle as well. This is not a proper solution, but it seems to fix the issue. I hope Google releases a new version with the fix.

Comment: Thanks, already fixed it in the same way, I'll accept this answer as it works for me.